# ASP.NET problem with XSLT transformation

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

I need help with the following issue. I parse XML and do a XSLT transformation. Everything is fine with Stylus Studio. But with ASP.NET I can't parse and output.

min.aspx.vb

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.XPath
Imports System.Xml.Xsl
Imports System.IO


Partial Class Poseidon_min
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Protected Sub Literal1_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Literal1.PreRender

        Dim strXSLTFile As String = "http://www.kiris-alinda.de/Poseidon/Hotelangebote.xslt"
        Dim strXMLFile As String = "http://www.kiris-alinda.de/Poseidon/PosXMLReq/PosXMLReqSearch.php?htc=AYTLIND"



        Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(strXMLFile)

        Dim objXSLTransform As New XslCompiledTransform()

        objXSLTransform.Load(strXSLTFile)

        Dim htmlOutput As New StringBuilder()

        'Dim htmlWriter As TextWriter = New StringWriter(htmlOutput)

        'objXSLTransform.Transform(reader, Nothing, htmlWriter)


        Me.Literal1.Text = htmlOutput.ToString()

        reader.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Why is it not possible to output `<xsl:value-of select="PosXmlResponse/search/date/@min"/>` from the XSLT in ASP.NET?

Comment: I looked at the source XML and it has `<date von="" bis="" min="" max="" for="Y-m-d" />` so the XSLT you have is correctly outputting nothing but the empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this :

[XML / XSLT Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35b30hy4%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

You have to use an XML Server Control on the ASPX page and then setting up XSLT Transformation

Comment: The XML Server Control does not work with url xml only local. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You can use DocumentSource to specify a remote URL... 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xml.documentsource(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: In .net 2.0 remote URL was not possible as I remember. As your tipp comes closest to a solution, I marked it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:

```
Public Shared Function Transform(xml As String, xsl As String, argsList As XsltArgumentList) As String
    Dim selectedXml As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml)
    Dim xmlTransform As New XslCompiledTransform()

    Dim htmlOutput As New StringBuilder()
    Dim writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(htmlOutput)

    xmlTransform.Load(New XmlTextReader(New StringReader(xsl)))
    xmlTransform.Transform(selectedXml.CreateReader(), argsList, writer)

    Return htmlOutput.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: thx for your feedback. does this work with asp.net 2.0? I have probs with XDocument. Which is not known. Is there a additional @imports?